# Notify update of Tooltip Value (wpf)

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid, notify

I have a Datagrid structure in xaml and several columns inside it:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="QualityValueColumn" Binding="{Binding QualityValue}">
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding MySelf, Converter={StaticResource ItemToTooltipConverter}}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="48000"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

I need to notify an update at the Tooltip value when a internal process is finished.
How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to force the recalculation of the Converter then you just need to Raise the PropertyChanged event from your process in the last.
It should be something like RaisePropertyChanged(<< Property Name >>) or a PropertyChanged( << Property Name >>). This would explicity invoke the control tooltip property to refresh itself.
Note the property name should be the same as which is binded to the ToolTip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done the converting from item to tooltip content in a dependency property in the item's datacontext. Therefore, when the process is finished you Raise property change of this "ToolTipContent" property, and thats it. In the property's Set you should create the content.